# Field formats lost when using action region and output panels

Tags: visualforce

My problem is I need to wrap a label and it's field inside an output panel in order to show / hide BOTH the field and the label dynamically. Doing so causes the field / label to lose formatting with the rest of the page. I've read answers that say how to circumvent this using different tags, but not ones that deal with both outputPanels and actionRegions. For example, if I move the outputLabel *outside* of the outputPanel, formatting is preserved, but then the label is not hid when it's respective field is hidden.

```
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 <apex:outputLabel value="Multiple Dates?" for="MultipleDates"/>
                <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputField id="MultipleDates" value="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates__c}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="MultipleDates1_Wrapper, MultipleDates2_Wrapper" />
                </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel id="MultipleDates1_Wrapper">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Multiple Dates 1" for="MultipleDates1" rendered="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates__c}"/>
            <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputField id="MultipleDates1" value="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates_1__c}" rendered="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates__c}"/>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel id="MultipleDates2_Wrapper">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Multiple Dates 2" for="MultipleDates2" rendered="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates__c}"/>
            <apex:actionRegion>
                 <apex:inputField id="MultipleDates2" value="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates_2__c}" rendered="{!Consultant_Request__c.Multiple_Dates__c}"/> 
            </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `layout="none"` to your output panel?

Comment: @Bachovski just tried, they don't even show up when that's added.